# ng-model as initial input on form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I have an edit form that pushes data to a mongo db using express and angular. I am using ng-model for my data. The **PUT** works correctly to update the database. But I can't seem to make that found data as initial values on the input fields in my **GET**. I think I am binding things incorrectly. If that is the case, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

**My controller**

```
app.controller('EditController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    var self = this;
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/users/' + $routeParams.id,
        data: $routeParams.id
    }).then(function(response) {
        // console.log(response.data);
        self.id = $routeParams.id;
        self.name = response.data.name;
        self.age = response.data.age;
        self.gender = response.data.gender;
        self.img = response.data.img;
    });

    this.editForm = function() {
            console.log('editForm');
            console.log('Formdata: ', this.formdata);

            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/users/' + $routeParams.id,
                data: this.formdata,
            }).then(function(result) {
                self.formdata = {}
            });
    } // end editForm

}]);
// end EditController

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true});

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/match_partial.html'
    }).when('/edit/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/edit_partial.html',
        controller: 'EditController',
        controllerAs: 'editctrl'
    })

}]);
```

**My HTML**

```
<div>
    <a ng-href="/">
        <br>
        <h3 class="back">Back to Match</h3>
    </a>
    <h1 class="editHeader">
        Edit {{editctrl.name}}    
    </h1>
    <form ng-submit="editctrl.editForm()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="editctrl.formdata.id" placeholder="{{editctrl.id}}">
        <input type="text" ng-model="editctrl.formdata.name" placeholder="{{editctrl.name}}">
        <input type="text" ng-model="editctrl.formdata.age" placeholder="{{editctrl.age}}">
        <input type="text" ng-model="editctrl.formdata.gender" placeholder="{{editctrl.gender}}">
        <input type="text" ng-model="editctrl.formdata.img" placeholder="{{editctrl.img}}">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set the whole object to receive the `response.data`, this way:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/users/' + $routeParams.id,
  data: $routeParams.id
}).then(function(response) {
  // console.log(response.data);      
  // Here 
  self.formdata = response.data;
});
```

And it will *automatically* fills all inputs with the object properties.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. If you can explain a little bit why it was not liking my previous code, I would really appreciate that. If not, I will investigate further the cause of the earlier problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help :) If you want to set it manually (which is completely unnecessary), you should do this way: `self.formdata = {}; self.formdata.name = ...`